# What is up with [A-Z] meaning [A-Za-z]?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, grep

I've noticed for a while now that, on some of the Unix-based systems I use at least, `ls [A-Z]*` has been giving me the results I would anticipate from `ls [A-Za-z]*`, leaving me unable to easily get a list of just the goddamned files that start with capital letters.  I just now ran into the same thing with `grep`, where I could not get it to stop matching lowercase letters with `[A-Z]` until I eventually used `grep -P` to get Perl regex.

So I have some related questions:

1. When did this idiocy start?
2. Who is responsible and needs to be punished?
3. ***WHY???***
4. Is there some reasonably simple workaround for either or both of the `ls` and `grep` cases?  (Trying, for example, `grep --no-ignore-case` was fruitless.  `grep -P` is not a very good workaround because of its experimental feature status.)

Comment: `[[:upper:]]` is another option.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I have some kind of allergy to those constructs and never think of them.

Comment: Stumbled upon this while searching for something different, and upvoting because your related questions cracked me up. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually `[A-Za-y]`, and it has to do with language collation. If you want to override it then set `$LC_COLLATE` appropriately; either of `C` or `POSIX` should do.

Comment: Oh, thank you thank you.  `[A-Za-y]`?  I'm terrified to ask, but why `y` and not `z`?

Comment: Because `Z` is before `z` in the collation order.

Comment: Oh, I love committee-designed standards so much it hurts me.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your locale. If you want that `[A..Z]` only matches capital letters, you could use C locale: set `LC_COLLATE` or `LC_ALL` to `C`.

```
LC_ALL=C
ls [A..Z]*
```

[bash manual, pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: But then, the downside IMO of this is that when you `ls`, you get all the uppercase files first and then all the lowercase... and as a result, most of the time, you have to look in two places for a file you can't remember whether it starts with an uppercase or a lowercase. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Unix shells don't actually use regular expressions, but *glob patterns*, which are distinctly different from regexes.  One difference is that they are implicitly anchored to the start and end of the string - e.g. `ls foo[a-z]` will list the file `food`, but not `fooble`. It's not actually `ls` doing the matching here, but the shell itself. Globs are also <strike>usually</strike> sometimes *case insensitive* (depending on the implementation).

Take a look at the manpage for your favourite interactive shell and read about glob matching - for example [bash's manpage about filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) describes the syntax it uses.

Comment: You're right that the shell uses globs rather than regexps, but globs are case-sensitive.

Comment: @wnoise: hmm, I think that part is implementation-dependent; I'll do more research.