# Why does "grep '[^ -~]'" behave identically to "grep -P -L '[^[:ascii:]]'"?

Tags: bash, shell

I've been assigned to grab files that only contains ASCII text. I found this code online but just don't get it.

```
grep '[^ -~]'  $someargument
```

I found this has the same functionality as:

```
grep -P -L -r '[^[:ascii:]]' $someargument
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with _grab files that only contain ascii text_. Do you mean you want to find all the file names of all the files that only contain ascii text?

Comment: `grep -P -L -r '[^[:ascii:]]' $someargument` needs to work. but what is your question here?

Comment: Your previous question got closed for a reason! Don't ask a new one that is identical with the previous one! The duplicate: [Could anyone explain what this line of code means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320388/could-anyone-explain-what-this-line-of-code-means).

Comment: @Simonare My question is why this line of code "grep '[^ -~]'  $someargument " also work

Comment: @PesaThe I think Ive already clarified the context of my question

Comment: @kvantour Yes you are right, thats what my question means, sorry for not being very clear

Comment: And [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320388/could-anyone-explain-what-this-line-of-code-means#comment95460014_54320388) explained to you, in your previous question, why it does not belong here. Nonetheless, after checking out your other questions, I recommend reading those posts: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: As I told you in comments to the other question, `[ -~]` is depending on locale-specific collation order and *doesn't* work reliably across systems with different language configurations. Because it doesn't work reliably, it's not something you should think of as "working" at all.

Comment: The two commands have quite distinct behavior in many cases. If `$someargument` refers to a single file, the `-r` is redundant; and the `-P` option is inconsequential for this particular use case (the regex you use does not require `-P` and specifying it does not change `grep`'s behavior).  What remains I think is "why does `grep oneregex` behave the same as `grep -L oppositeregex` where the two regexes are properly complementary, which isn't strictly the case here.

Answer (score 2):

*Note:*

The answer assumes you are using only locales where POSIX [[:ascii]] is matching with [a-zA-Z] range.

In regex, you specify a range like [a-z] for matching any lowercase alphabet. Behind the hood, the regex engine actually checks for the code points (byte values) anywhere between 97 and 122.

Similarly, the regular expression [^ -~] matches any code point in the ascii chart that are not between 32(space) and the tilde (~) which is 126. So this is generally used to check if a particular string contains only the human readable text ( that are in the keyboard :-) ). That is, it is used for cleaning the string values.

If you have any control character say control-A, \x01, in the string, the regex will match and you can remove them using the regex_replace() functions.

Refer this ascii chart below.

[image: ascii chart]

Consider this example:

```
$ cat -vT tommy.dat
abc^Adef  # control-A
ghi^Iprq # tab-character
hello
hai

$ grep "[^ -~]" tommy.dat
abcdef
ghi     prq

$
```

Note: The regex [^ -~] will match for newline, tab, control feed which are generally allowed in multiline strings but you may want to exclude them in the match

In that case, you can specify [^\n\t\r -~]

Comment: The ASCII chart is misleading, since not all locales follow that order! Using it to formulate ranges for `grep` is thus a great way to get code that works on some systems but not others. (This is why `[A-Z]` is *not* always the same as `[[:upper:]]`, f/e; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834353/what-is-up-with-a-z-meaning-a-za-z)

Comment: @charles.. yes with different locales the POSIX syntax and the range [A-Z] is different.. for this context looks like the OP is dealing with only ASCII files doing some cleanup and so I pasted here..

Comment: They could well be dealing with ASCII files, but if they're doing so on a system with a non-ASCII locale (or a script they write is later run by a different user on such a system), they're open to surprises.

Comment: @Charles.. yes right.. I'll add it to the answer.. limiting to US-ASCII and ISO-8859-1 character sets..